# C++ character check

Tags: c++

I have just started to learn C++ and i would like to get some help.
The user needs to type an ID number and the format has to be the following. The first character `B` and the other 4 any integer.
Im trying to check if the character format are right.
So far i have this:

```
if ((isalpha(id[0])=='B' ) && (isdigit(id.at(1))) && (isdigit(id.at(2))) ......
{
  //do something
}
else
{
    cout << "Wrong format" << endl;
}
```

but even if i type example `B8745` it says wrong format.

Comment: So break the line down into little pieces and find out which condition is failing. Then, examine what the values of `id` really are, and you'll know _why_. Nothing for us to do here.

Comment: `isalpha(id[0])` returns a `bool` value, that's unlikely equals `'B'` ever!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, it returns an `int` value, to be pedantic.

Comment: @DonReba The return type is `int` correct, but the values are either `true` or `false`:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, no the value is either "0" or "not 0". If the character is alphabetical, the return value could be `true` or any other `int` other than 0. Strictly speaking. :)

Comment: To those voting to close this question: this question is exactly what we are here for: to help others, not *just* build a Q&A website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the result of `isalpha`, which is boolean, to character literal 'B'.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the code for ID[0] == 'B' || 'b' without isalpha and the rest is the same. Now Its working. Thanks again.

Comment: @bontoo `ID[0] == 'B' || 'b'` will not work as you intend it. You should use `(ID[0]=='B' || ID[0]=='b')` otherwise that statement will *always* be true. In C/C++ `'b'` is a non-zero integral value, which will be counted as true in case of boolean operator.